# Three fair dice are rolled thrice: Probability of getting a "double 5" at least once?

Tags: probability

> Three fair dice are rolled thrice. What is the probability of getting a "double 5" at least once?

I was thinking that it is $$\frac 16 \cdot \frac 16 \cdot \frac 56 \cdot 3$$

Comment: Three fives count too...

Comment: so does it mean 1/6 * 1/6 * 6/6 * 3 = 0.083

Comment: Oh, I may have misread the problem. "Three fair dice are rolled thrice". You roll three dice and see if you have a "double five". Then repeat two more times?

Comment: When you have to compute the probability $p$ that an event happens at least once, it is usually easier to compute first the probability $1-p$ that this event never happens.

Answer (score 1):

1/6 * 1/6 * 5/6 * 3 is the probability that you get double 5's on a given throw.

If you wanted to get doubled 5's EACH of the three times, then you would cube the result.

However, if you want the probability of getting a "double 5" AT LEAST once, you should calculate the probability that it does not happen, and then subtract that number from 1, as Gilles Bonnet said.

Probability of not getting double 5 on a throw = 1- (1/6 * 1/6 * 5/6 * 3)
probability of not getting double 5 on any of the throws p = (1- (1/6 * 1/6 * 5/6 * 3)) ^3
probability of getting a "double 5" at least once= 1-p = 1- (1- (1/6 * 1/6 * 5/6 * 3)) ^3

Answer (score 1):

- $\frac 16 \cdot \frac 16 \cdot \frac 56 \cdot 3$ is the probability of a "double five" but not a "triple five" on a single roll of three dice.
- Add $\frac 16 \cdot \frac 16 \cdot \frac 16$ if you want to include a "triple five" in the calculation.
- Subtract from $1$ to get the probability not to get a "double five" on a single roll of three dice.
- Put to the power of $3$ to get the probability not to get a "double five" on any of three rolls of three dice.
- Subtract from $1$ to get the probability of getting a "double five"  at least once on three rolls of three dice.